# Ubuntu server LVM not using entire disk space

Tags: server, partitioning, lvm

Running `lsblk` gives following output.

```
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda                         8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1                      8:1    0     1M  0 part 
├─sda2                      8:2    0     2G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0 463.8G  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   100G  0 lvm  /
sdb                         8:16   1     0B  0 disk 
sr0                        11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

As we can see here the LVM size is 100 GB, though total disk space is around 563.8 GB.

Running `sudo vgdisplay` shows output as below :

```
Alloc PE / Size       25600 / 100.00 GiB
Free  PE / Size       93122 / <363.76 GiB
```

My question : how can i utilize the complete space which i am not able to right now.

Thanks